# Options for deploying Custom azure polices in Management group

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am looking to Automate deploying custom policies to Management group in Azure

For example

[image: sample Hierarchy of Management group]

I have a Management group created in Azure. Under it there are inherited Management groups, and under those there are subscriptions, refer to the image.

I have policies and Initiatives (a group of policies clubbed together as initiatives). I want to assign different initiatives to Management group A and B. However, when I assign independently, I don't see any option where the root management group can understand that my policies/Initiatives are already assigned/deployed to child Management groups.

How would I make root Management group understand that the child management groups are assigned to respective polices?

Comment: its not clear what you are asking, there is no concept of `service` in the management group. what do you call a `service`?

Comment: My bad, updated the description with more readability

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is no capability for that yet

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no function for this in the UI. If you want to see what your child management groups assignments are, you have to select that scope.